# It seems a lot of questions are closed and obliviated

Tags: discussion

I notice a lot of questions about 9/11, the holocaust etc keep getting obliviated to the sasquatch page. I think this gives a really bad image to our site. Can we handle these situations in a more mature way?

Comment: I've similar issue [here](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3694/8014).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about [this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35249/does-the-scientific-method-prove-that-the-official-9-11-story-is-false/35250#35250) (high rep users can see it).

The question was closed as a duplicate by 5 users, was at -5 score and had multiple bad answers and consequently people arguing in comments.

Keeping bad questions with bad answers is certainly worse than removing them for the site.

I am sorry you don't find this a mature reaction, I disagree on that. Furthermore, I find that claiming that questions are deleted based on topic, without providing any proof of this, is assuming intentions and very unconstructive for the site. Avoid this in the future.

Comment: How much rep do you need to see that?

Comment: @Bobb http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: Ok well if someones conspiracy theory is wrong then it should be easy to refute or close as duplicate.

Comment: `Ok well if someones conspiracy theory is wrong then it should be easy to refute` lol, if it were that easy. Oftentimes, when you refute it using, say, data from NASA, it’s simply because they’re in on the conspiracy. It’s an endless game. I know there’s serious conspiracy theorists with whom you can actually have a conversation but they are few and far between.